# Mutating nested object/arrays as states in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateful

I am using React components which look like this (a simplified version of the components I used, below).

My question is: how to make the same but using this.setState?
The below code works, but I am mutating the state directly, and I am receiving the following warning:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playerState: [
        {
          name: 'Jack',
          hp: 30
        },{
          name: 'Alan',
          hp: 28
        }
      ],
    };
  }
  lowerPlayerHealth = (index) => () => {
    this.state.playerState[index].hp = this.state.playerState[index].hp - 1
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Player 1: {this.state.playerState[0].name}</p>
        <p>Health: {this.state.playerState[0].hp}</p>
        <button onClick={this.lowerPlayerHealth(0)}>Hit player 1</button>
        <p>Player 2: {this.state.playerState[1].name}</p>
        <p>Health: {this.state.playerState[1].hp}</p>
        <button onClick={this.lowerPlayerHealth(1)}>Hit player 2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When rendered, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: A simple read through the [setState() docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) would make this a trivial problem to solve yourself

Comment: @charlietfl I'll read over it

Comment: if `this.state.playerState[index]` is passed as a prop into child component and this child component is `extends PureComponent` it will never re-render on change. It's just a first use-case when mutating state can completely break something in your app.there are a set of reasons following the docs and never mutating state.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify an existing value in the state, you should never get the value directly from the state and update the state object, but rather use the updater function in `setState` so you can guarantee the state values are the ones you need at the time of updating the state. This is just how React's state works and it's a very common React mistake.

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.
>
> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being
>   used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.
>
> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:
>
> `(state, props) => stateChange`
>
> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is
>   being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes
>   should be represented by building a new object based on the input from
>   state and props.
>
> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed
>   to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with
>   state.

So you must get the value exactly when you want to update the component inside the setState function using the first argument of the updater function.

```
lowerPlayerHealth = (index) => () => {
    // use setState rather than mutating the state directly
    this.setState((state, props) => {
    // state here is the current state. Use it to update the current value found in state and ensure that it will be set correctly
      return (state); // update state ensuring the correct values
    });
  }
```

**Solution**

To lower a value found in state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playerState: [
        {
          name: 'Jack',
          hp: 30
        }, {
          name: 'Alan',
          hp: 28
        }
      ],
      };
  }

  lowerPlayerHealth = (index) => () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      state.playerState[index].hp -=1; //update the current value found in state
      return (state); // update state ensuring the correct values
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Player 1: {this.state.playerState[0].name}</p>
        <p>Health: {this.state.playerState[0].hp}</p>
        <button onClick={this.lowerPlayerHealth(0)}>Hit player 1</button>
        <p>Player 2: {this.state.playerState[1].name}</p>
        <p>Health: {this.state.playerState[1].hp}</p>
        <button onClick={this.lowerPlayerHealth(1)}>Hit player 2</button>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: using React we should never mutate state. your code does it.

Comment: @skyboyer what do you mean with "we should never mutate the state", do you mean we should never use setState? I'm lost...

Comment: I mean our code with `setState` should work the way when you return new object each time when need to change single property deep nested. otherwise `PureComponent` will never re-render. Some details: https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

Comment: @skyboyer actually you should not use PureComponent with objects with deep nested properties... or maybe I'm wrong. [about PureComponent and state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) states "Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state". Could you please expand your idea so I can have a proper read on the matter and learn about this? thank you!

Comment: `PureComponent` actually works with complex structures/nested objects. but if for `Component` state mutation rarely can cause issues for `PureComponent` it will definitely break something - and since it's easier to control when props are plain values - it's suggested. nothing special behind actually.

Comment: @skyboyer I think we are off the track here... it is suggested that PureComponent should not use complex objects, but of course it will work if you do it properly. The main question was about mutating the state directly, and using setState and mutating the object within setState is the way to go and to solve this issue as stated in the answer's documentation. Please correct me if I'm wrong and feel free to update the answer if you feel it's doing something improper. It's always good to learn something new and to correct any mistakes.

Comment: no, it really works. I still believe it is not _React-way_ but it would be rather opinion-based than _no-no_ thing. I'd rather create a dedicated answer with my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question: don't mutate state.  Also, best practice suggests using the function version of `setState`.

Since `playerState` is an array, use `Array.map` [to create a new array containing the same objects](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/), replacing only the one you want to change:

```
lowerPlayerHealth = (indexToUpdate) => () => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    playerState: state.playerState.map(
      (item, index) => index === indexToUpdate
        ? {
          ...item,
          hp: item.hp - 1
        }
        : oldItem
    )
  }));
}
```

If you made `playerState` an *object* instead of an array, you can make it tidier:

```
lowerPlayerHealth = (indexToUpdate) => () => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    playerState: {
      ...state.playerState,
      [indexToUpdate]: {
        ...state.playerState[indexToUpdate],
        hp: state.playerState[idToindexToUpdatepdate].hp - 1
      }
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: `this.state.playerState` should be an object not an array to allow `[index]:` approach. for array it should be another `.map()`-based pattern used. could you update your answer?

Comment: @skyboyer array-like indexing works for objects and arrays.  I made you [an example](https://jsbin.com/nabivejuzo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: but you are converting array into object. if you keep `playerState` as array you will get `unexpected token` error

Comment: @skyboyer you're right.  How would you approach this keeping it as a single `this.setState` call but retaining the array?  (please feel free to edit my answer)

Comment: done, check updated version